# How can I check if a certain string is at the start of a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to preg_match a string .basically if i got a string which is given to a variable

```
$line = " <szFilename> &#6; ds  </szFilename>  "
```

And I need to check if the sting starts with `"<szFilename>" .`
am finding a hard time finding the pattern.
What i tried is

```
$line=" <szFilename> &#6; ds  </szFilename>  ";
//$line2=" <szFilenamed1> &#6; ds  </szFilenamed1>  ";
//echo trim($line);
if(preg_match("/[<szFilename>]*/",trim($line))){
    echo "GOT IT";
 }
```

Any help?

Comment: Where are we with this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a regex here. Just simply use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to determinate if the string is at the start (index 0) or not, e.g.

```
if(strpos(trim($line), "<szFilename>") === 0) {
    echo "success";
}
```

If you want/need to use a regex, just use an [anchor](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) (`^`) to match your regex at the start, e.g.

```
if(preg_match("/^<szFilename>/", trim($line))) {
    echo "success";
}
```

Also if you are writing your own regex's, I can highly recommend this site: https://regex101.com/, which highlights everything nicely and you get an nice explanation to the right, what your regex does.

Comment: use `strpos(...) === 0` to avoid the case when strpos() returns false

Answer (score 2):

Just `'/^\s*<szFilename>.+/'` is all you need.